# Entity Framework: How to get data from related table (many to many)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have two tables

```
LOCATIONS:
Id
Name
OwnerId (FK to Owners table)

PARAMTERS:
Id
LocationId
TypeId
Name
Value
```

The data is something like:

```
LOCATIONS
1,'Park',100
2,'Shop',200
PARAMETERS
1,1,'Length',5,200
2,1,'Width',5,100
3,2,'Area',6,100
```

I want to retrieve the data for all locations that will include all parameters for each location.

I have a query that doesn't work.

```
_locationsRepository.GetAll()
      .Include(x => x.Owner)
      .Include(x => x.Parameters)
      .ToList();
```

Running this without including Parameters works fine.
There is FK(to Locations table) in Parameters table.

Am I missing something?
Would be glad if anyone could help.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? and the GetAll() implementation

Comment: The query looks correct to me. Maybe you've forgotten to setup the foreign key relationship?

Comment: I have only foreign key on Parameters table, what else do I need?

Comment: GetAll() implementations comes from IRepository.GetAll method. IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>.GetAll Method (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/api-docs/html/M_Abp_Domain_Repositories_IRepository_2_GetAll.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try and add something like:

```
[InverseProperty("Location")]
public virtual ICollection<Parameters> Parameters { get; set; }
```

to your Locations table and add

```
[ForeignKey("LocationId")]
public virtual <Location> Location { get; set; }
```

to the Parameters table to allow for reverse lookup and help EF generate the foreign key correctly (assuming that you are using CodeFirst of course).

Both of the tags live inside

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```